# How do I issue an http request after proxy pass? Using openresty (lua + nginx)

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I have a similar need to https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/issues/220

**My use case**

1. I'm forwarding files to a remote server, through using `proxy_pass`.
2. I need to pass `$body_bytes_sent` to a remote url, after proxy pass.
3. I thought about doing a `content_by_lua` block, with an `ngx.capture` forwarded to the `proxy_pass` block, with an `ngx.say()` returning what came from `ngx.capture`. Followed by a request with $body_bytes_sent to the remote url. But I need to support streaming, which this wouldn't do. And files can get quite big which is bad for `ngx.capture()`.
4. I thought about doing a `log_by_lua` block, but cosockets apis are disabled. https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#log_by_lua

Comment: Not think this is a bit overkill, we do something similar, i.e. tracking request information, however, you could use beats to trawl this information and define the log file in NGINX. Maybe post this up to a logstash instance

Comment: The block that contains the `proxy_pass`, has an `access_by_lua` block that queries a microservice. In our setup, the microservice is fed data from `log_by_lua`, which lets it determine if a particular url should be accessible or not. ---- The remote server inside `proxy_pass` is out of our control. So we couldn't have done it there. --- Logstash was given some thought. But I thought it would have complicated things, since I would have needed to send a copy of the logs to the microservice.

Comment: Do you found "something that doesn't block the nginx worker" for sending data over http?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Still have the blocking operation.

Answer (score 1):

**Install Lua-Curl or another library that does not depend on cosockets**. (https://github.com/Lua-cURL/Lua-cURLv3)

If you're using luarocks (comes with openresty), install with

`apt-get install libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4-openssl-dev --yes`

`luarocks install Lua-cURL`

Use `log_by_lua` (e.g. log_by_lua_block, log_by_lua_file), like this.

```
# some nginx conf

location /a_location_with_proxy_pass {
    proxy_pass https://example.com:443;
    log_by_lua_file /path/to/luafile.lua;
}
```

**Your log_by_lua_file should then do the curl request to the remote server.**

```
local cURL = require 'curl'

curlHandle = cURL.easy{
    url        = 'https://remote_host.com/endpoint',
    post       = true,
    httpheader = {
        'Content-Type: application/json';
    },
    postfields = '{"bytes":' .. ngx.var.body_bytes_sent .. '}'
};
curlHandle:perform();
```

Comment: The bad thing here is that you will BLOCK nginx worker until response recevied.

Comment: I'm afraid so. I prefer `proxy_pass` to `ngx.capture` - because I'm dealing with files. But this means, I only get `$body_bytes_sent` available in `log_by_lua` which does not allow cosockets.

I would prefer something that doesn't block the nginx worker, but couldn't find anything else. If you have anything else, even just ideas, would love to hear it! :D